# C# program crash (.ico file)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

The program crashes if there's no .ico file inside the same folder. I have:

1. Added the MyIcon.ico file in the Application section, also 'embed manifest with default settings' is checked.
2. Made the .ico file as Embedded Resource (Build Action) in the .ico file properties.
3. Added `this.Icon = new Icon("plat.ico");` in the Public form.

So... why is the application not booting? What gives?

Comment: Ugh, I meant 'this.Icon = new Icon("MyIcon.ico");'
My mistake. Still not booting

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Maybe its something obvious like your startup form or no application entry point?

Comment: Any Exception details to go with the crash?

Comment: Any reasons that you feel that it is all about the ico file? Cause the info you gave, is actually some sort of procedure for adding ico file. Where does your bug start?

Comment: The error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test3\test3\bin\Release\MyIcon.ico'.

this error highlighted the code line: this.Icon = new Icon("MyIcon.ico");

Answer (score 4):

The [constructor for Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yt46ccy.aspx) you are using tries to read "plat.ico" as a filename, not from embedded resources.

If you want to load the Icon from resources, you will need to explicitly get a `Stream` from the resource, then pass that into the Icon's constructor.

This will likely be something similar to:

```
// Add using System.Reflection; at the top of your file...

this.Icon = new Icon(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.plat.ico")
  );
```

Alternatively, you can use the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5bzkwt9.aspx) that pulls directly from a resource, by name, instead of a filename:

```
this.Icon = new Icon(this.GetType(), "plat.ico");
```

Comment: @Mark: I was working on it ;)  The string you pass in depends somewhat on where you put the icon file.  Here's a link with more details: http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/how-to-load-an-icon-from-an-embedded-resource-in-c/

Comment: Doesn't work :/ I get this error: Additional information: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a windows form, where the icon could not be found even though it was in the same directory as the form.

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("enabled.ico");
```

I looked at the .ico file's properties in VS2010 and saw that *Copy to Output Directory* was set to *Do not copy*. I changed it to *Copy always* and that did the trick.

Sometimes the simplest solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the icon file's "Copy to Output" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".

Answer (score -1):

You are invoking wrong constructor. Just use this:

`this.Icon = new Icon(this.GetType(), "plat.ico");`